# Whats the internal functionality difference between 'npm install &>/dev/null' and 'npm install --silent' and 'npm install --quiet'?

Tags: npm

`npm install &>/dev/null` and `npm install --silent` and `npm install --quiet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “quiet” flag suppresses all log levels below “warning”. Only warnings and errors will be printed.

The “silent” flag suppresses all log messages.

The `&>/dev/null` prints log messages normally (from NPM), but stderr is discarded (by the OS). It will look like “silent” but the mechanism is different. `&>/dev/null` is not specific to NPM and is actually interpreted by your shell (e.g. Bash, Zsh).

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config